# Font smooth issue, fonts are not looking good in Debian QT [Embedded Qt]

Tags: linux, qt, fonts, embedded-linux, x11

I am using qt-x11-opensource-4.8.2 Debian Jessie on BBB Embedded device.

Steps I have tried to solve the Issue:

1. Configured the Qt font libraries and Transferred to the Board -> configured the font path properly.
2. Qt Creator Build & Run Changes has been done to run the Qt application on the Embedded device. Added the Environment variables [QTDIR, QT_QWS_FONTDIR & LD_LIBRARY_PATH] to the Build setup.
3. Downloaded all the QtGui Dependencies libraries for X11 in Embedded device.
4. X Rendering Extension; used for anti-aliasing, Run the application as cmd: ./Teledyne -xrender
5. Q_WS_X11 macro is defined in the code for support embedded Linux project, which will Export all X11 related functions.
6. Used the Qt Resource Embedded Fonts [Roboto & VeraBd] and Run the application
7. Used the Qt PreferAntialias and PreferFullHinting option to enable the smooth font.
8. Installed the basic font packages and configure them
   cmd : apt-get install ttf-dejavu ttf-liberation
9. Using the XLFD -X logical font Description
   cmd : xfontsel
   Tried to change the font width point size and pixel size
10. Configure the XTT and Created a xtt font folder and loaded the font path to the Xservers session
    cmd: xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/xtt
11. Checked whether the lightdm may depends of the font configuration
    created file : ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
    link:https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/lightdm/2015-April/000785.html
12. Create a file called .fonts.conf in home directory -> added content for the antialiasing, which will Enable subpixel-hinting and font-smoothing
    Link:https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts
13. Created a Qt application with the few available fonts e.g.dejavu sans,Fixed[Sony],Bitstream Vera Sans,Courier,dejavu serif,Times
    Tested the above fonts Qt application in the Device.

Any suggestions what might be causing this Issue ?

Please can any one help me on this, I am struck :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Did you get the solution yet? Cauz I am facing the same problem but with windows! You can check that out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61697971/why-fonts-in-qt-are-appearing-blurry-or-pixelated?noredirect=1#comment109135442_61697971

Answer (score 0):

> Are you compiling Qt with support for [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/)? 
>   We have been having similar problems related to bad rendering and
>   sometimes even non readable fonts, and after installing the dev
>   package of fontconfig and recompile Qt with support for fontconfig
>   everything works as expected.

At the end we've been getting again same problem of fonts being shown incorrectly ( basically bad rendering ) and was because RenderType uses which is defaulted to "Text.QtRendering" and we need to use "Text.NativeRendering" to have the proper rendering on platform used ( linux ).

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#renderType-prop ->
>   Select Text.NativeRendering if you prefer text to look native on the
>   target platform and do not require advanced features such as
>   transformation of the text. Using such features in combination with
>   the NativeRendering render type will lend poor and sometimes pixelated
>   results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: recompile Qt with support for fontconfig - can you please explain what u have done in steps