# Why fonts in Qt are appearing blurry or pixelated?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, qt, fonts, pyqt5

All my fonts are appearing pixelated, so I used `AntiAliasing` but it isn't helping out. As you can see the pixelated font in the image itself:

[image]

This is the code I am currently using:

```
butt1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("""Scrappr""")
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
font.setPixelSize(22)
font.setFamily('Segoe UI Bold')
butt1.setFont(QtGui.QFont(font))
```

I tried different solutions on SO, qtforums etc but nothing works for me :(

**I tried:**

- Different combinations of `ClearType text` but It didn't work out as, by default all the text appears good on windows and chrome **but** with `Qt` only, it becomes pixelated.
- Changing windows aero theme to classic one...

But none of them helped.

**Here are My PC Specs:**

- windows: 7 ultimate
- PySide2 version: 5.14.2.1
- Resolution: 1360 X 768

Comment: try https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QFont.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QFont.setStyleStrategy with `QFont.PreferAntialias`

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10. When I used Qt 5.13 all fonts were rendered correctly. After installing Qt 5.14 this problem appeared. Today I installed Qt 5.15 thinking the problem has been solved, but fonts are the same, like you described. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Okay... Seems like I am not alone here. Thanks for letting me know  @INeed-ADollar

Answer (score 8):

I'm using BrownPro font and the texts were blurry at all resolutions, but much more evident at low resolutions.

I was able to solve the issue by setting the hinting preference for the font to: `PreferNoHinting`. Applying it at the application level, fixes the issue everywhere.

Here is the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#HintingPreference-enum

And here is the code I used:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/BrownPro-Bold.ttf");
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/BrownPro-Regular.ttf");
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/BrownPro-Light.ttf");

QFont brown_pro_font("BrownPro");
brown_pro_font.setHintingPreference(QFont::HintingPreference::PreferNoHinting); //This line did the trick
QApplication::setFont(brown_pro_font);
```

Comment: This absolutely works! Also using Qt6. Text displays a lot better (on windows) since I set this hinting preference.

Comment: I have been scratching my head all day over this problem, and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to work with Qt last year and i used qml for building the UI part of my application.

Qt itself prefers us to use qml for building UI, since they have written a UI engine that renders everything better compared to the old engines.

In case of PyQt you are using the python only approach which is only not usually recommended, i am not saying that the qml version is pixel perfect. it still works bad at drawing curves (but that is not the stuff we usually require). As far as your problem is concerned qml will work fine for you (it has much better text rendering).

You might struggle a bit finding the learning resource for qml. But at least give it a shot and yes it is easier much easier than Python only approach.

Comment: software build using old approach might produce different font renders on different operating system. but qml approach has same output on all the operating systems

Comment: Thanks for answering @Arish-Khan Will `QML` work with `PySide2` too?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/qml.html try this

Comment: Well, I have tested it. It works fine with fonts like "Arial" or "Times new" only but not with "Helvetica". What should I do now? Will it solve if I use Windows 10 :( @Arish-Khan

Comment: well i am not sure, i haven't used Helvetica. The fonts i used with qml were Roboto, Google Sans etc... those worked fine for me but i haven't tested Helvetica

Answer (score 2):

Try to see the fonts used by PyQt5:

```
import PyQt5
from pyQt5 import QtGui
dir(QtGui.QFont)
```

the result will show all you need for QFond and the fonts can be used:

```
[..., 'Helvetica',...,'SansSerif',..., 'Serif',..., 'Times', ...
```

You can try to add your custom fonts but you need to test each font.

For example, [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QFont.html) tells us:

*In Windows a request for the “Courier” font is automatically changed to “Courier New”, an improved version of Courier that allows for smooth scaling. The older “Courier” bitmap font can be selected by setting the PreferBitmap style strategy (see setStyleStrategy() ).
Once a font is found, the remaining attributes are matched in order of priority:*

```
fixedPitch()

pointSize() (see below)

weight()

style()
```

Comment: I just have one question. Is it happening to windows 7 users or the same problem is with windows 10 or macOS also?

Comment: Also, I want to add that all the fonts that you mentioned are still pixelated (i mean a lot). I TRIED THEM ALL JUST NOW...

Comment: these fonts are used by default by QFont, maybe your source code has problems. Try to edit your question with full source code, or a basic example, also try to see the Courier New font if this has the same problem then it is from source code or something else.

Comment: Yes, it does have the same problem with `Courier New`!! What to do now?

Comment: you need to find why the Courier New is more good, see the link about Courier New. Good luck.

Comment: No matter how good the fonts will be. They will still be pixelated for me : ( You said something about source code... What should I do next?

Comment: I wonder, is it related to font size scaling? What is the font size percentage in the Windows control panel? Set it to 100%, and see if the text is still blurry.  https://www.pcworld.com/article/242942/how_to_change_font_size.html